# Performing a count on an item that never has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using either JavaScript or jQuery, is it possible to capture a count on an item on a page that never get focus from the user and is only used to store values into it from another item that has the user focus?

I basically require a means of counting the total number of entries that are going into a item as that item gets populated.

Comment: A count of *what*?  You're being a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hidden field within a form should work

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvar1()
{
var x=document.getElementById("var1")
return x;
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="http://www.address.com/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="var1" value="myvariable">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i dont really know what you mean but are you trying to do this.. where you count the text in the box?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type='text' id='var1' onkeypress='javascript:magic();' onkeyup='javascript:magic();' value="hi">

<div id='displaydiv'>Waiting..</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function magic(){
    document.getElementById('displaydiv').innerHTML = ""+(document.getElementById('var1').value.length);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ross but could you please provide the trigger mechanism to perform the calculation. Thanks.

Comment: get element by the id, and now you can use JS to call that function

Comment: Thanks for the example - how about when I haven't posted the page as yet but need to calculate a count prior to posting?

Comment: see the edit, if you want anything else you'll have to be more clear